# SDL Tridon 2013 SP1 Apache Tomcat 7.0.x Upgrade to 7.0.60

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

We have SDL Tridon 2013 SP1 running on live environment. Our client has run a vulnerability test on server and found security issues with Apache Tomcat below is detailed issue reported.

Is it possible to upgrade Apache Tomcat 7.0.x to 7.0.60 on SDL Tridon 2013 SP1?

Any pointer or help will great to fix this issue.

> **Name :** Apache Tomcat 7.0.x < 7.0.60 Multiple Vulnerabilities (FREAK)
>
> **Descripton :**
>
> - According to its self-reported version number, the Apache Tomcat service listening on the remote host is
>   7.0.x prior to 7.0.60. It is, therefore, affected by the following vulnerabilities :
> - A NULL pointer dereference flaw exists when the SSLv3 option isn't enabled and an SSLv3 ClientHello is received. This allows a remote
>   attacker, using an unexpected handshake, to crash the daemon,
>   resulting in a denial of service. (CVE-2014-3569)
> - The BIGNUM squaring (BN_sqr) implementation does not properly calculate the square of a BIGNUM value. This allows remote attackers
>   to defeat cryptographic protection mechanisms. (CVE- 2014-3570)
> - A NULL pointer dereference flaw exists with dtls1_get_record() when handling DTLS messages. A remote attacker, using a specially crafted
>   DTLS message, can cause a denial of service. (CVE-2014- 3571)
> - A flaw exists with ECDH handshakes when using an ECDSA certificate without a ServerKeyExchange message. This allows a remote attacker to
>   trigger a loss of forward secrecy from the ciphersuite.
>   (CVE-2014-3572)
> - A flaw exists when accepting non-DER variations of certificate signature algorithms and signature encodings due to a lack of
>   enforcement of matches between signed and unsigned portions. A remote
>   attacker, by including crafted data within a certificate's unsigned
>   portion, can bypass fingerprintbased certificate-blacklist protection
>   mechanisms. (CVE-2014-8275)
> - A security feature bypass vulnerability, known as FREAK (Factoring attack on RSA-EXPORT Keys), exists due to the support of weak
>   EXPORT_RSA cipher suites with keys less than or equal to 512 bits. A
>   man-in-the-middle attacker may be able to downgrade the SSL/TLS
>   connection to use EXPORT_RSA cipher suites which can be factored in a
>   short amount of time, allowing the attacker to intercept and decrypt
>   the traffic. (CVE-2015-0204)
> - A flaw exists when accepting DH certificates for client authentication without the CertificateVerify message. This allows a
>   remote attacker to authenticate to the service without a private key.
>   (CVE-2015-0205)
> - A memory leak occurs in dtls1_buffer_record() when handling a saturation of DTLS records containing the same number sequence but for
>   the next epoch. This allows a remote attacker to cause a denial of
>   service. (CVE-2015-0206)
> - A use-after-free condition exists in the d2i_ECPrivateKey() function due to improper processing of malformed EC private key files during
>   import. A remote attacker can exploit this to dereference or free
>   already freed memory, resulting in a denial of service or other
>   unspecified impact. (CVE-2015-0209)
> - An invalid read flaw exists in the ASN1_TYPE_cmp() function due to improperly performed booleantype comparisons. A remote attacker can
>   exploit this, via a crafted X.509 certificate to an endpoint that uses
>   the certificate-verification feature, to cause an invalid read
>   operation, resulting in a denial of service. (CVE-2015-0286)
> - A flaw exists in the ASN1_item_ex_d2i() function due to a failure to reinitialize 'CHOICE' and 'ADB' data structures when reusing a
>   structure in ASN.1 parsing. This allows a remote attacker to cause an
>   invalid write operation and memory corruption, resulting in a denial
>   of service. (CVE-2015-0287)
> - A NULL pointer dereference flaw exists in the X509_to_X509_REQ() function due to improper processing of certificate keys. This allows a
>   remote attacker, via a crafted X.509 certificate, to cause a denial of
>   service. (CVE-2015-0288)
> - A NULL pointer dereference flaw exists in the PKCS#7 parsing code due to incorrect handling of missing outer ContentInfo. This allows a
>   remote attacker, using an application that processes arbitrary PKCS#7
>   data and providing malformed data with ASN.1 encoding, to cause a
>   denial of service. (CVE-2015-0289)
> - A flaw exists in servers that both support SSLv2 and enable export cipher suites due to improper implementation of SSLv2. A remote
>   attacker can exploit this, via a crafted CLIENT-MASTER-KEY message, to
>   cause a denial of service. (CVE-2015-0293) Note that Nessus has not
>   attempted to exploit these issues but has instead relied only on the
>   application's self-reported version number.
>
> **Solution :** Upgrade to Apache Tomcat version 7.0.60 or later.
>
> **Information :** Installed version : 7.0.39 Fixed version : 7.0.60

Answer (score 3):

7.0.39 and 7.0.60 are both classified as 7.0.x. Looks like you’re on 7.0.39 and all you need is a minor version upgrade to 7.0.60. Unless the SDL prerequisites are specific to a minor version, which I doubt (but double check this), you are good to upgrade.

Comment: The [Tridion 2013 SP1 Content Delivery prerequisites page](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-DBBDB18C-93AC-4E8E-B529-A9321E706C9A) just says Tomcat v7.0 (and v6.0) are supported, so I agree with Nick and would assume that upgrading to v7.0.60 is fine.

Answer (score 2):

We did a scan on a client site recently (2013 SP1 HR1) and found a couple of JARS (3rd party, but required). We worked with Tridion Support and received a patch for the affected JARs.

I'd contact support directly as the first port of call, of course, bearing in mind 2013 is now in limited support your mileage may vary but it would be useful for others to know what the formal line is in the specific items you note.

Comment: Or upgrade if that's feasible - as pointed out by Nick :)